# PowerShell - Get VMName, VMNetworkAdapter, SwitchName,IsLegacy, Vlanlist

Tags: powershell, hyper-v

So far I've figured out that piping these cmdlets will get me everything I need EXCEPT for the "VLANLIST"

```
Get-VM | Get-VMNetworkadapter | ft VMname,NAme,SwitchName,isLegacy -Autosize
```

I would be totally satisfied if this could also tell me what vlan the network adapter for each vm is operating on.

This cmdlet does what I want: `Get-VMNetworkAdapterVlan`

But of course it doesn't give me the switchname, or islegacy values.

I can't find a way to marry that cmdlet to the one I previously presented.

What combination works?

Comment: `foreach ($VM in (Get-VM)) {$VM | Get-VMNetworkadapter | Get-VMNetworkAdapterVlan}`  could work however I can't check up it (not having the `Hyper-V` enabled). Maybe `foreach ($VM in (Get-VM)) {$VM | Get-VMNetworkadapter | ForEach-object { $VmNetA = $_; $_ | Get-VMNetworkAdapterVlan}}` and apply the _calculated properties_ concept in the output.

Comment: Thanks for your input. It's a new way of looking at the problem. The cmdlets above don't produce anything much different from just running "get-vmnetworkadaptervlan" I'm missing the switchname for each adapter and the islegacy field. I'm educating myself with calculated properties article and see what I can do: https://mcpmag.com/articles/2017/01/19/using-powershell-calculated-properties.aspx

Comment: ok I based on my reading I trieD:  foreach ($VM in (get-vM) {$VM | Get-VMNetworkadapter | Select-Object -Property *,@{Name = 'Switc
hName' ; Expression = { $SomethingName = $_NSwitch; (@(SwitchName).where({$_.NSwitch -eq $SomethingName})).PatName | Get
-VMNetworkAdapterVlan}}    In that cmdlet I smushed together the variable $Switchname = Get-vmnetworkadapter -property Switchname. Not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a custom object with the properties you are looking for from the separate commands:

```
$virtualmachines = Get-VM 

$vmvlans = Get-VMNetworkAdapterVlan -VM $virtualmachines 
$vmnetworkinfo = @()

foreach ($virtualmachine in $virtualmachines)
{


                $virtualnetworkadapters = Get-VMNetworkAdapter -VM $virtualmachine 
                $vmvlans = Get-VMNetworkAdapterVlan -VM $virtualmachine 
                $vmproperties = New-Object -TypeName PSObject
                $vmproperties | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name VMName -Value $virtualnetworkadapters.vmname 
                $vmproperties | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Name -value  $virtualnetworkadapters.Name
                $vmproperties | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name SwitchName -Value $virtualnetworkadapters.switchname
                $vmproperties | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name isLegacy -Value $virtualnetworkadapters.islegacy
                $vmproperties | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name VlanList -value $vmvlans.accessvlanid
                $vmnetworkinfo += $vmproperties

}

$vmnetworkinfo | ft VMname,Name,SwitchName,isLegacy,VlanList
```

You may need to change the Vlan property you're looking for based on your environment, of course.

Comment: Please read [this **performance related**  comment](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/220780/powershell-loop-through-nested-objects#comment426748_220780): roll down to _Appending to arrays_ in the [Slow Code: Top 5 Ways to Make Your PowerShell Scripts Run Faster](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/ashleymcglone/2017/07/12/slow-code-top-5-ways-to-make-your-powershell-scripts-run-faster/) article.  Use `$vmnetworkinfo = foreach ($virtualmachine in $virtualmachines) { …  $vmproperties }` omitting both `$vmnetworkinfo = @()` and **very slow** `$vmnetworkinfo +=`

Comment: Please read [this _accepted_ answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/220879/88771) as well. Instead of `$vmproperties = New-Object -TypeName PSObject` and all that  talkative `$vmproperties | Add-Member  …`, use (hopefully more legible) `$vmproperties = [PsCustomObject]@{
 VMName     = $virtualnetworkadapters.vmname;
 Name       = $virtualnetworkadapters.Name;
 SwitchName = $virtualnetworkadapters.switchname;
 isLegacy   = $virtualnetworkadapters.islegacy;
 VlanList   = $vmvlans.accessvlanid;
}`

Comment: Any idea how to export this data to csv ? When I do |  Export-CSV C:filename.csv after vlanlist  the data in the file is giberrish. With ClassID Colums, PageHeaderEntry, etc.

Comment: That seems to be the object type information.

Comment: What's the best way to display all the information properly? I changed the last line from ft to Select-Object VMname.......VlanList | Export-CSV C:\file.csv and I get system.object[] in a few cells.

Comment: Try -expandproperty VMName after Select-Object before exporting to the CSV.

Comment: `Invoke-Command -ComputerName hypervserver -FilePath D:\Documents\PSTools\Get-VMNetworkDetailsV2.ps1 | select VMName,name,SwitchName,isLegacy,VlanList -ExpandProperty VMName | Export-Csv C:\vmnetworkdetails.csv`

Comment: Says "Cannot validate argument on parameter 'VM."  The argument is null or empty. Either by adding -expandproperty VMName or running it in your last example.

Comment: It works fine for me, the only thing I changed from the last example was the output filepath.

Comment: Something weird is happening. I just went back and ran the exact script you posted yesterday and now its saying "Get-VMnetworkadaptervlan  Cannot validate argument on parameter 'VM'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try command again." I'm running as admin. It worked fine yesterday.

Comment: This probably won't make a difference, but I have not needed to run that with admin.